# Unexpected error while using mysql through Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Here is my source code which is error free. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. It gives an unexpected error saying "java.sql.driver" and I don't know what to make of that.

```
String v=jTextField1.getText();
    DefaultTable DefaultTableModel = null;
    DefaultTable model;
    model = (DefaultTableModel);
    jTable1.getModel();
    try
            {
            Class.forName("java.sql.driver"); 
            Connection c;
            c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://local host/hospital","root","hope");
            Statement s=c.createStatement();

            String q;
        q = ("Select * from hospital where Patient_Name=v");

            ResultSet r=s.executeQuery(q);
            while(r.next())
            {
                int PNO=r.getInt("PNO");
                String Patient_Name=r.getString("Patient_Name");
                int Age=r.getInt("Age");
                String Gender=r.getString("Gender");
                String Department=r.getString("Department");
                String Doctor=r.getString("Doctor");
                model.addRow(new Object[]
                {PNO,Patient_Name,Age,Gender,Department,Doctor});


                r.close();
                s.close();
                e.close();
            }
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the mysql jdbc driver in netbeans library?

Comment: log `SQLException` and put stacktrace here

Comment: `local host`? It is not valid host name.

Comment: @devd yes i have

Comment: [1] You need to give more information about the error saying "java.sql.driver". What is the full and exact text of that error message? Where was it logged? [2] Also, as talex has already pointed out, `local host` should be changed to `localhost`. Make that change and test again to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @skomisa yes i have done the changes and now the error says "you have an error in your Sql syntax"

Comment: OK, so the problem is with your query `"Select * from hospital where Patient_Name=v"`. What is **v** supposed to represent? Also, [take a look at some sample MySql queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html), which may be helpful.

Comment: @skomisa v is the value i'm supposed to be getting from a textfield which is basically a patient's name

Comment: @HibaAkhlaq `"Select * from hospital where Patient_Name=v"` here `v` is a string variable so you need to add it like this:
`"Select * from hospital where Patient_Name=\""+v+"\""`

Comment: @devd it worked thank you soo much